# .last method working weirdly rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an Model named Page

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :details, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and Detail

```
class Detail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
end
```

Everything was working fine, but now when I call

page.find(29).details.last(2), it gives

```
 [#<Detail id: 379, followers: 1055869, follows: 42, media_count: 325, page_id: 29, created_at: "2017-03-15", updated_at: "2017-03-16 19:31:26">,

#<Detail id: 309, followers: 785870, follows: 0, media_count: 0, page_id: 29, created_at: "2017-03-10", updated_at: "2017-03-10 23:30:10">]
```

and if I try page.find(29).details.last

```
 #<Detail id: 309, followers: 785870, follows: 0, media_count: 0, page_id: 29, created_at: "2017-03-10", updated_at: "2017-03-10 23:30:10">
```

why its showing record with `id= 309` as latest instead of 'id=379'

To clarify I manually updated record with `id=309` before this issue,

I tried to update `id='379'` but still its showing last record as `id=309`
(moreover I also changed created_at type to date from datetime a month ago as I needed it)

'm I missing something or its actually weird (its on live server I really need to fix it)

Regards

Comment: If record `379` is returning first in the `last(2)` call, it means it's not actually the last record. The last record in the array returned by `last(2)` is equivalent to `last`. That means that 309 is actually the last record, as Rails sees it. What SQL is being run? This smells like a default scope affecting your query.

Comment: Also, in a default Rails setup, changing created_at to a 'date' is a bad thing. The default sort in rails is by created_at, so in updating it, you may have messed with the order you were expecting.

Comment: @chrismanderson
Thanks, I understand last(2) thing, added it to clarify between 309 and 379. its postgre. yes created_at as date might have caused issue.
But I changed it a month ago, it was working fine

Comment: What is the actual SQL being run? Should be able to find that from your logs, or run the query in console and add an `explain` to the end.

Comment: @chrismanderson
I added posgre gem, its on cloud66, I hope that its postgreSQL.

can't find from logs, but I can run that on console
whats "explain"? can you provide an example

Comment: `last` should use `order by id desc limit 2`

Comment: @Iceman I 'm expecting same, but its really weird

Comment: You have some `default_scope` in your model?

Comment: Also, if you try this in your console you will see the actual sql being used.

Comment: can't see query on server but at local its desc by id like "SELECT  "details".* FROM "details" WHERE "details"."page_id" = $29 ORDER BY "details"."id" DESC LIMIT $2"

Comment: I used "Page.find(29).details.find(Page.find(29).details.maximum(:id))" to work for now.

But really interested in finding the reason